# A wild This appears!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Now you don't see me, now you do
>   Didn't expect that, or did you?
>
> I'm sorry, did I ruin your view?
>   It's just my thing, that's what I do
>
> Whatever you saw, now it's something new
>   I just appeared to reveal what's true
>
> Well, actually, lie is the real clue
>   Cuz once you see me, you can
>   undo

**What am I?**

Comment: The title makes me think of Pokemon Go :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's an easter egg. I thought it would be cool effect :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Now you don't see me, now you do

Didn't expect that, or did you?*

> Something that you see right in front of your eyes and next moment it's gone and reappears unexpectedly.

*I'm sorry, did I ruin your view?

It's just my thing, that's what I do*

> Something that keeps clouding your view with imagination.

*Whatever you saw, now it's something new

I just appeared to reveal what's true*

> Something that hides the reality even when you know it's not real.

*Well, actually, lie is the real clue

Cuz once you see me, you can undo*

> And once you find out the trickery you can undo it.

Is it...

> **Optical Illusion**

Comment: Explain lines, and be more specific, and you got it!

Comment: Sure, Might take a few minutes to format it.

Comment: I'll mark as correct, because you explained well, but few details are missing. try to be more specific, what type of illusion?

Comment: Maybe it's opt...?

Comment: I was thinking white out. 1-2) It's something that makes the visible (text) invisible but is itself visible if you look closely. 3-4) It ruins your view of the text that was written. 5-6) It eliminates a mistake so you can put the correct information in its place. 7-8) It lets you undo the mistake you just wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> a shadow?

*Now you don't see me, now you do*
*Didn't expect that, or did you?*

> A shadow appears or disappears according to how strongly, and from which direction, the light is shining.

*I'm sorry, did I ruin your view?*
*It's just my thing, that's what I do*

> Shadows tend to darken things and ruin views.

*Whatever you saw, now it's something new*
*I just appeared to reveal what's true*

> A shadow reveals the shape of the real ('true') object whose shadow it is.

*Well, actually, lie is the real clue*
*Cuz once you see me, you can undo*

> Once you see a shadow, you can easily get rid of it by shining light on it.

Comment: No, but god damn you, it's a nice answer actually. Think more about how lie is the clue.

Comment: @oxArt, think I have it

Answer (score 1):

It could be on a more abstract theme

> **The truth**

Now you don't see me, now you do
Didn't expect that, or did you?

> You never know when you'll see the truth, or do you?

I'm sorry, did I ruin your view?
It's just my thing, that's what I do

> Once you know the truth of something you look at it differently

Whatever you saw, now it's something new
I just appeared to reveal what's true

> Same as above and the truth reveals what's true

Well, actually, lie is the real clue
Cuz once you see me, you can undo

> Lie is the opposite, but once you know it's a lie you know whats true. Once you see the truth you can undo your errors

Comment: No, not "abstract".

Comment: @oxArt, Damn, thought I had it with 'lie is the real clue'